# python Permission denied when running chromedriver

Tags: python, ubuntu

I created a module that would go to chrome driver website and download the latest driver and extract it into a directory.

```
r = requests.get(r'http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_linux64.zip', stream=True)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall()
```

However, when I tried doing the below code. It gave me a Permission denied error.

```
driver_path = r"/home/jakewong/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get(r'http://www.google.com')

out: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

But when I went to manually download the file from the same link and extract it to the folder, I was able to run `driver` code with no issue.

What seems to be wrong here? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Wild guess, `chromedriver` executable has to have `+x` permissions for user running Python interpreter?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean you should apply appropriate permissions (`chmod`) before trying to executing chromedriver.